# "Object not callable" when echoing posted image

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to listen for a file being sent over post with the key `'image'`, then return it back to the caller.

```
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def img():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return "yo, you forgot to post"
    else:
        img = request.files['image']
        resp = make_response(img)
        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

This fails with the message:

> TypeError: 'FileStorage' object is not callable

I'm not massively familiar with Python, but I thought by doing the above that I was passing the `byte[]` straight through memory?

How do you achieve this without it failing? I want to take it the image blob from the request, manipulate it (not currently), and return it straight back out. In memory, without saving it to the file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can serve out the image again with the [`Flask.send_image()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file); it accepts a file-like object as well as filenames. You'll have to copy the file data over to an in-memory file object (the `request.files` file objects are closed too early to be suitable):

```
from io import BytesIO

return send_file(BytesIO(request.files['image'].read())
```

You may want to add additional headers, such as the mime-type, to the response as the `send_file()` function has less information to go on here than with 'regural' file objects. The sending browser probably included a content type for example:

```
import mimetypes

img = request.files['image']
mimetype = img.mimetype or mimetypes.guess_type(img.filename)[0]
return send_file(BytesIO(img.read()), mimetype=mimetype)
```

This does require you to hold the whole image in memory.

Comment: Ah, well there we go, thanks. This may warrant a new question, but doing so gives me a `WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'F:\\Workbench\\<root>\\img'` Is this an issue with file path formats running Python on Windows, or an actual problem? Same issue running inside/out of a virtualenv

Comment: @KaelanFouwels: sorry, better work-around produced now.

Comment: @KaelanFouwels: hrm, on Mac systems this still results in reading an already closed file object.

Comment: @KaelanFouwels: then you no longer have a file object; I'll have some more time in a minute to come up with a better option.

Comment: Oops. Turns out .stream doesn't work under Windows either, same error you mentioned. I must have forgotten to check in after adding it - my bad

Comment: @KaelanFouwels: I'd love to create a better solution than 'hold in memory' but because sending out the file requires a temporary file to remain open until the WSGI server is done reading from it, there is no good way to clean up the temporary files *from Flask*. You'd have to use a cron job to periodically clean up temp files created this way.

Comment: Ah well, it'll do for what I need. Thanks greatly for the help